# siunitx package not working in tables

Tags: tables, siunitx

I can't get the special table columns from the `siunitx` package to work. The numbers render in a normal `l` column but not in the special `S` coulmn. Here's my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \num{1.445e12}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|S[tabformat=1.5e12,tabnumalign=left]|}
        \hline
        \num{1.445e12} & \num{1.445e12} \\
        \hline
        \num{95}       & \num{95}       \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Result here

[image: preview]

Not only is exponentiation not working in the table cell, but the numbers aren't even left-aligned. The same result is produced with `pdflatex` and `xelatex`.

Comment: The content of an `S` column is 'automatically' inside `\num`, which should therefore not be used. Please try without it wrapping up each entry.

Answer (score 6):

The column type `S` provided by `siunitx` sets the contents of the cell automatically as an argument of `\num`. So you definition is equal to:

```
\num{\num{95}}
```

which fails.
If you want that the cell isn't interpreted by `\num` you can put the cell in extra curly brackets `{TITLE}`.

Please note that some names of options have been changed. The package produces an error like

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! siunitx error: "version-1-option"
! 
! Version 1 option 'tabnumalign' detected.
! 
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

The documentation of `siunitx` lists all changes in an extra table. See section 8.1 Upgrading from version 1.

```
OLD          ==> NEW
tabformat    ==> table-format
tabnumalign  ==> table-number-alignment
```

By the way: Avoid vertical lines inside tables and be spare with horizontal.

Comment: `siunitx` documentation can be found [here](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/siunitx/siunitx.pdf).